# Submitting multipart/form-data using ajax in php is null

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

I have this kind of form:
method="post"
enctype="multipart/form-data"

Everytime the form is submitted via ajax

```
$("#openTicketSubmit").click(function(){
    var support_ticket_form_data = new FormData($("#support_ticket_form"));
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "{$systemurl}submit_ticket.php",
        data: support_ticket_form_data,
        contentType: 'multipart/form-data',
        success: function(results){
            console.log(results);
        },
        error( xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError ){
            console.log( thrownError );
        }
    });
});
```

It got an error: jquery.min.js:4 Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation
and then in the server side (php) the $_POST is null.

Please somebody help me.

Answer (score 1):

To do a multipart/form-data request with jQuery.ajax, `contentType` and `processData` needs to be set to false.

Also the FormData constructor takes a form object not a jquery one

```
var support_ticket_form_data = new FormData($("#support_ticket_form")[0]);
```

Comment: Thank you very much brother! this one solves the problem:
$("#support_ticket_form")[0]

I have another question, why is that when I echo the  $SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] it is null? :/

Comment: Do you mean `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']`?

Comment: yeah, I misspelled  the $_SERVER into $SERVER. Thank you bro.